# how to shift array items by adding new items at the beginning in Java

Tags: java, arrays, input

i want to get an input as integer that will declare which number will be the "new" starting point of the array and also make the previous indexes 0.

I mean let's assume the input entry is 1. So the array will start after the 2nd index. The previous indexes and the index of the input number will be 0, and the old array will be shifted (the last numbers will be deleted. The important point is the array must have 10 items. So the final result must be like;

```
a[]={2,3,1,8,4,5,7,6,0,9}; // original array has 10 items
```

input is 1. it is on the 2nd index. so the new array will start from the 3rd index.

```
{0,0,0,2,3,1,8,4,5,7}  //final array has 10 items
```

My code;
(I did it. it works but I do not want to use a second array. Is there any possible way to do this with 1 array?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Ex3{                           
    public static void main(String args[]) {   
        int a=0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Number: ");
        int  number = input.nextInt();
        int arr[] =  {5,9,7,1,20,11,6,8,30,9};     
        int arr2[] = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
        for(int i=0; i<arr.length;i++) {
            if(number== arr[i]) {
                if (a<10) {
                for(int j=i+1; j<arr2.length;j++){
                    arr2[j] = arr[a];
                    a++;
                }
                }
                System.out.print(Arrays.toString(arr2));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: i wrote a code block but when i give an input, it converts all the items to my input. like 55555555

Comment: @ArdaAltun Then **edit** the question and show us the code block you wrote, and we'll help you figure out why it fails. You did **debug** your code before asking here, right?

Comment: the `;` at the end of `if (i == number);` is wrong.

Comment: this is the final version of the code. everything is working now. but i don't want to use 2 different arrays. is there any possible way to do it by using only 1 array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the last digits of the array zeros and then swap the zeros with the non-zeros digits from the head of the array. Here is my code:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Number: ");
    int  number = input.nextInt();
    int[] arr =  {5,9,7,1,20,11,6,8,30,9};

    //Find the index of the number given from console and make the last digits zero
    //The number of zeros is equal to the index of the number given from console
    for(int i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
        if(number == arr[i]){
            for(int j=0; j<i+1; j++){
                arr[arr.length-1-j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    //Swap the non zero digits from the head of the array with the zeros from the tail of the array
    int index_non_zero_item = -1;
    int temp = -1;
    for(int i = arr.length-1; i>=0; i--){
        if(arr[i] != 0){
            index_non_zero_item = i;
            for(int j=arr.length-1; j>=0; j--){
                if(arr[j] == 0){
                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```